# Juniper J4350 out of order

Tags: router, boot, juniper, junos

I have got two (2) Juniper routers J4350 that are out of order :

- All the interfaces are down (leds on the interfaces don't ligthen, ping dosen't respond)
- No output on the console port (even when booting)
- I've tried to reset the router (holding the RESET CONFIG button on the front panel during 15 seconds) and nothing happened, even while booting the device
- I've opened the router to check the fans. I've removed some dust and nothing has changed.

I wanted to precise that the leds on the front panel are all on:

- The POWER led is green
- The STATUS  led is red
- The ALARM led is on and is orange
- The HA (High Availablity) is on and orange as well

I have found nothing on the Internet to solve this problem... 
Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: You might want to contact the company and have a repair ticket put in...

Comment: two routers? same EXACT issue? are the routing engines still installed? are you sure your serial connection is properly configured 9600-n-1 ?

Comment: The serial port was working fine until the router was down... I don't know what caused it: it was working really well and the next day when I booted it, it wasn't working.

Comment: I'd suggest removing all but the necessary cards, then re-seating them one at a time with the console plugged in.  Can you test/confirm the console cable is ok by testing it on another Juniper switch?  (I have experienced cables "go bad overnight", but in the end we found that the cable head got pulled hard and some wires broke.)

Answer (score 1):

The leds are useful, but not a lot...

- The POWER led is on, with a steady green. This mean that [the router
  is powered up](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/jseries/junos93/jseries-getting-started-2/power-button-and-power-led.html).
- The STATUS led is on. An [error](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/jseries/junos93/jseries-getting-started-2/status-led.html) has been detected. But it doesn't provide much more informations.
- The orange ALARM led [indicate](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/jseries/junos93/jseries-getting-started-2/alarm-led.html) a "Minor alarm condition [that] requires monitoring or maintenance". Not very useful, but they mention a possible license error.
- The HA led is not explained in this manual ('future use'), but [another version](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-es/junos-es91/junos-es-jseries-getting-started/ha-led_1.html) indicate that "one or more monitored links are down".

I don't know if a license error could possibly prevent the router from booting, but I think you should at least get a console prompt.

And I would open a case with [Juniper TAC](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB10910) for them to help you.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly :)
I do not have a console prompt, even when I boot the router...

I don't have any support anymore: I'm part of a group of students who are working on Juniper routers and our advisor bought the routers in 2008 and doesn't have support anymore

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced this condition on 12 of our 80 J4350's.  The only solution Juniper came up with was to install new DIMMs.